# CSS Animation - drawing line from left to right on mouseenter, then disappearing left to right on mouseleave

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a line that underlines from left to right on 'mouseenter' and then to disappear from left to right on 'mouseleave' instead of the current behaviour where it disappears right to left.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve (but with animations not transitions):

https://jsfiddle.net/1gyksyoa/

I have tried to reverse the 'draw' animation but this doesn't achieve what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
        @keyframes draw-reverse {
      100% {
        width: 0;
        background-color: red;
      }

      0% {
        width: 47px;
        background-color: red;
      }

}
```

I have put together this to give a better understanding of the problem;

https://jsfiddle.net/Lq560be9/

Currently, I have the line animating from left to right as desired on 'mouseenter', but on 'mouseleave' it disappears from right to left, whereas I am trying to get the line to also disappear from left to right.

Comment: I don't think this can be accomplished with just CSS—you'll likely need javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the problem isn't animation's ability it's the properties that you're animating. Instead of animating the width of an object you should animate its "X" position using `translate`. (this is much more performant too)

Simply put you need to MOVE the bar from left to center to right instead of trying to scale it.

(there's lots of code here to show the different states the only one you really need to follow is `.ex4`)

```js
document.querySelector('#animate').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  this.classList.toggle('over');
})
document.querySelector('#animate').addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
  this.classList.toggle('out');
})
```

```css
.example {
 margin: 30px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 background: #dadada;
 max-width: 50%;
 position: relative;
 }
 .example:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
 }
 
 .ex1:after {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
 
 .ex3:after {
  transform: translateX(200%);
 }
 
 .ex4 {
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 .ex4:after {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
 
 .ex4.over:after {
  animation: animate-in 1s ease-in-out 1 normal forwards;
 }
 .ex4.out:after {
  animation: animate-out 1s ease-in-out 1 normal forwards;
 }
 
 @keyframes animate-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    }
 }
 @keyframes animate-out {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200%);
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="example ex1">Object State 1</div>
<div class="example ex2">Object State 2</div>
<div class="example ex3">Object State 3</div>
<div id="animate" class="example ex4">Full example (hover)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a follow on from above, an alternative solution *without* using the translate property.

The new animation for mouseleave is;

```
@keyframes draw-reverse {

  0% {
    width: 47px;
  }

  25% {
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
  }
  26% {
    width: auto;
    right: 8px;
    left: 8px;
  }

  100% {
    width: auto;
    right: 8px;
    left: calc(100% - 8px);
  }
}
```

Full solution can be seen here - https://jsfiddle.net/1wq25tg7/